# Confusion regarding exact type and voltage of my laptop RAM module for upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a Toshiba satellite laptop C50-A. I am thinking to add more  RAM. It has currently a Micron DDR3-1600 Mhz PC3-12800  CL=11  Model 4KTF25664HZ-1G6E1 RAM Module. The confusion is this:
As I know from research DDR3 PC3 Ram runs on 1.5 v. But when I ran CPU-Z it shows my voltage is **1.35v** not  1.5 v. And the type of RAM shown is DDR3 on CPUZ not DDR3L. 
I ran a system scanner on crucial.com  and it recommends an upgrade to DDR3L RAM running at 1.35v.
And RAMMON shows voltage as 1.5v, 1.3v and DDR3.
So my question is  my RAM DDR3 running at 1.5 V or DDR3L running at 1.3v.

Comment: Simple search gives https://www.micron.com/parts/modules/ddr3-sdram/mt4ktf25664hz-1g6 which gives an answer that Your RAM is DDR3L. Which means it can run at 1.35V(which it most likely does in Your notebook). It also supports 1.5V(for those old chipsets, which don't support lower voltage).

Comment: Thank you. My part no shown on various apps I ran says 4KTF25664HZ-1G6E1 without MT prefix shown on the datasheet. Just wondering if it is the same module. I should probably physically check the module.

Comment: MT means just Micron Technology. With or without MT it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for knowing at what voltage your RAM is running at would be your BIOS/UEFI.

To enter your BIOS/UEFI you need to read the prompts that appear right after you press the power-on key on your computer from a power-off state and press the correct one.
 Probably F2 or DEL.

Some googling says your current RAM runs at 1.35V and unless you changed your BIOS/UEFI settings and overclocked it, I am inclined to believe this. Could be possible that your MOBO "expects" to run RAM at 1.5V and forces that voltage setting.. But.. That seems less likely to me.

All in all, You are probably running a DD3 RAM at 1.35V and you want your upgrade to be a 2nd RAM kit exactly equal to the first.

Take this with a grain of salt and consider it suggestions and speculation.

Comment: @BobbySha In that case, trust CPU-Z. It's very reliable. Maybe double check with AIDA64.